# Сокращение названия "Бонусные баллы"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сократить фразу "Бонусные баллы" на сайте. Например, 15 бонусных баллов, варианты: 15 ББ, 15ББ, ББ15 или ББ 15. То есть с пробелом или без, число ставится перед сокращением или после, или вообще есть другой формат написания. Что правильнее?

Answer (score 10):

Не знаю, может ли любой желающий придумывать новые сложносокращенные слова. На мой взгляд, нет, да  и понятнее будет без всяких сокращений. Например,на этой страничке  я подвожу курсор цифрам возле моего форумного имени и полностью вижу слова "очки уважения". И никаких ОУ. Но, наверное, на Вашем личном сайте Вы можете ввести такое сокращение, если хочется. Пробел между цифрами и буквами нужен.Но главное, чтобы это сокращение было всем понятно.

Comment: ларf, после третьего повтора этих "бонусных баллов" сам захочешь чего покороче. Не будете же вы настаивать, что РФ вместо "Российская федерация" неправильно?

Comment: Не буду. По-моему, это общепринятое и всем понятное сокращение.

Comment: Так для тех, кто на том сайте обитает, ББ тоже мождет быть понятное и общепринятое.

Answer (score 2):

С пробелом - точно, ибо пробел нужен после всякого числа.
Остальное - не регламентируется, как и вообще допустимость подобного сокращения.

Я бы написал "15 ББ", поскольку в таком виде фразу все-таки можно прочитать относительно беспроблемно. Откуда взялась идея писать сокращение перед число - даже и предположить не берусь. Разве от манеры писать знак доллара (и подобные) перед суммой. Но на то были особые резоны, да и сама рекомендация потеряла актуальность.